# Restar horas al GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito hacer una `query` que me muestre un conteo de todos los registros que existen en un rango de tiempo determinado.

Por ejemplo que me diga cuantos registros existen en la tabla tomando la fecha actual de hoy (`GETDATE()` fecha actual es 2019-08-07 09:03:00) restando le 3 horas (quedando 2019-08-07 06:03:00).

si ejecuto la consulta solo con la fecha actual me trae 200 registros que contienen fecha desde el 2019-08-07 00:00:00 hacia adelante. (no es como debería ser)

Si ejecuto la consulta con la misma fecha anterior pero restando le 3 horas (fecha actual 2019-08-07 09:03:00) quedaría 2019-08-07 06:03:00 me trae 100 registros que comienzan desde 2019-08-07 06:03:00 hacia adelante.

¿Como lo hago en una query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primera instancia probé con la siguiente `query`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [TotalRows]
FROM [mi_db].[dbo].[mi_tabla] WHERE EventDate > CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())
```

Me traía los 200 registros contando desde la fecha actual (2019-08-07 00:00:00)

Finalmente lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [TotalRows]
FROM [mi_db].[dbo].[mi_tabla] WHERE EventDate > DATEADD(HH, -3, GETDATE())
```

Esto hace que a la fecha actual que recupera desde el `GETDATE()` le evaluamos las `HH` para finalmente restarle `3 horas`

Answer (score 0):

habrá algo así para mongodb? resulta que al momento de guardar un registro eran las 19:30 y se guardó con 5 horas mas y cambió la fecha al día siguiente. A mi nueva consulta quiero agregarle 5 horas mas para que me devuelva ese dato,quiero poner la fecha real que guardé el registro y no poner la fecha del día siguiente. ayudaaaa please!!

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/345768)